# помогите разобраться с математической частью задачи

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно взять прямоугольник со случайным размером (например 2000х1000) и неограниченное кол-во маленьких прямоугольников разных размеров (размеры маленьких прямоугольников меньше большого например 150х200), эти маленькие прямоугольники нужно разместить на первом большом прямоугольнике так чтобы они занимали минимальное пространство на нём. если на большом прямоугольнике заканчивается место, то берется еще один такой же прямоугольник.

всё делается в 2d и программа делается под пк

Comment: Можно ли поворачивать прямоугольники (на 90 градусов)?

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). в частности по поводу заголовка почитайте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да, можно и поворачивать их

Comment: как определяется минимальное пространство? почему маленьких прямоугольников неограниченное количество? Если количество неограниченное, то и занятое пространство будет неограниченное.

Comment: да, пространство неограниченное может быть, а на счет прямоугольников то их может быть сколько угодно

Comment: Вы же вчера уже спрашивали, и я подсказал название задачи

Comment: "сколько угодно" и "неограниченно" это разные количества. Первое - это конкретное число, хоть и неизвестное в начале, второе - бесконечность. Как вы собираетесь уложить бесконечное количетсво прямоугольников, чтобы они заняли минимальное пространство? Бесконечное количество займет ВСЁ пространство.

Comment: нет нет я не правильно написал там должно быть сколько угодно

Comment: Если именно "сколько угодно", то возьмем  0  маленьких прямоугольников.  Они займут площадь 0. (Меньше никак.) Что-то не так, в постановке задачи.

Comment: `эти маленькие прямоугольники нужно разместить на первом большом прямоугольнике так чтобы они занимали **минимальное** пространство на нём` Берем наименьший прямоугольник, размещаем - мы заняли минимальное пространство.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть что-то в стиле тетриса?) Типа ты условно разбиваешь большой прямоугольник на множество маленьких квадратиков, так же поступаешь и с остальными прямоугольниками, по квадратикам ты понимаешь какие заняты, какие доступны, ну а далее размещаешь каждый новый прямоугольник на тех квадратиках, которые свободны и наиболее близко расположены к занятым